# How do I initialize this variable?

Tags: java, jgrasp

I understand that I need to initialize the variable daysInMonth, but I don't know how to since it's value at the point where I need it to determine the validity of the day is dependent on the user's input.

```
int daysInMonth; //number of days in month read in
```

part of code that determines daysInMonth

```
if(month == 1)
   daysInMonth = 31;
```

code where I get the error

```
//User number of days in month to check to see if day is valid
if(day > 0 && day <= daysInMonth)
   dayValid = true;
else
   dayValid = false;
```

Comment: do like this `int daysInMonth=0;`

Comment: You need a default value for daysInMonth otherwise you cant compare it with day in your if statement. What should daysInMonth be if month does not equal 1?

Answer (score 1):

Think what daysInMonth should be for other values of `month`. Add an `else`, or may be `else if`. Make sure all possible values are covered, with initialization or an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This initialization is not enough :

```
if(month == 1)
   daysInMonth = 31;
```

Since `daysInMonth` will only be initialized if `month==1`.

The safest way is to initialize `daysInMonth` when you declare it, and change its value when necessary (based on the `month`).

```
int daysInMonth == 31;
if (month == 6)
   daysInMonth = 30;
...
```

Another option is to have a method that takes a month and returns the `daysInMonth`. Then you can initialize your variable by calling :

```
int daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(month);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping it simple and doing it like this:

```
daysInMonth = 31; // Default value for the month
if(month == 2) {
   daysInMonth = 28;  // Change value if the month is febuary
} else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month== 9 || month==11) {
   daysInMonth = 30; // Change value if the month should have 30 days
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to guarantee initialization of a variable.

```
int daysInMonth; //number of days in month read in
if(month == 1)
    daysInMonth = 31;
```

This only initializes the variable if month is 1. If it isn't 1, it has still been uninitialized.

There are two approaches to solving this issue:

#### 1. Initialize the variable at the beginning

By giving your value a default value, you guarantee it is not `null`.

```
int daysInMonth = 0; //number of days in month read in
if(month == 1)
    daysInMonth = 31;
```

#### 2. Initialize the variable at every branch

By intentionally not defining it, **you can have the compiler tell you if you are missing any paths.** This may be helpful for complex if/else statements where variables have specific values, and you don't want to accidentally default to 0 for a state where it should be -1, for example.

```
int daysInMonth; //number of days in month read in
if(month == 1)
    daysInMonth = 31; 
else if(month == 2)
    daysInMonth = 28; 
//...
else if(month == 12)
    daysInMonth = 31; 
else 
    daysInMonth = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, but you can try this:

```
int[] days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
daysInMonth = days[month-1]];
```

**That's it! 2 lines of code is all you need.**

If you need to check for leap year...you can try this:

```
int[] days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int[] daysLeapYr = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

if (year % 4 == 0) //Leap year
    daysInMonth = daysLeapYr[month-1]];   //where month is 1-12 (Jan to Dec)
else
    daysInMonth = days[month-1]];
```

This way, you keep your codes clear with minimal `if-statements`.

If you are not checking for leap year, you don't even need any `if-statements`.